# Triggering a controller action after new/create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2.18
Ruby 2.1.5
```

In my controller, I have new and create methods. I have another method in the controller, let's call it post_create that I would like to automatically trigger after the create method finishes executing. This method has no view associated with it, and it's supposed to update a table.

I tried doing

```
after_filter :post_create, only:[:create]
```

But I need the parameters that were passed to the create method, and at this point I no longer have them. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by 'parameters that were passed to the create method?'. You should be able to e.g. access the params hash in your after filter.

Comment: You mean pass the parameters as part of the call to the other method?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in this way:-

```
def create
 #code
 redirect_to post_create_path(parameter)
end

def post_create
  #update the table
  redirect_to desired_path
end
```

**Note:-** Set the path by knowing the routes by typing in the console as `rake routes`.

Answer (score 0):

You will get params in you after_action. If this is not the case. You can perform such action in observer. If this is something that does not affect your new view. Then you should go for observer instead of creating a after_action. For mor detail check [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html).